# python: How to change the size of the bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want my bar plot abscissa become wider according the students' number.
When the number of students is 18, the plot seems good:

[image]

However, when the student number is more than 100, it is a mess:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
# Bar chart-----Final Grades per students
plt.figure(1)

names=np.arange(N)+1

barChart=plt.bar(names,height=final_grades,width=0.5,alpha=0.8)


plt.ylim(-3, 13)  
plt.axhline(0,c="r", ls="--")
my_x_ticks = np.arange(0, N+1, 1)
plt.xticks(my_x_ticks)

# legend the exact grade of each student
for i in barChart:
    height = i.get_height()
    plt.text(i.get_x() + i.get_width() / 2, height, s=height, ha='center', va='bottom')

plt.title(u"Final Grades per student")
plt.ylabel("Grades")
plt.xlabel("Students")
```

Comment: Pass a `figsize` when plotting?

Comment: A little unclear what you are asking here. Would you like the plot itself to become larger (wider)?

Comment: Yes! I want the plot itself to become bigger when the student's number increase.